# Hashing In Django Views

Tags: python, django

I'm passing data through ajax by attaching it to my element. The data is sensitive that if a user changes it they could change the associated field of another user (not sensitive like a password).

On this page a Teacher can view their Students. The Teacher can select the checkboxes of the lessons a Student has finished. So I can't just get Student from request (current user).

I want to hash this data (student_id) prior to inserting it into the template, then unhash it in my view when I receive it from ajax. I can't find how to do this in Django.

```
<form>
    {% csrf_token %}
    # student_id is the sensitive data
    <td class='class_complete' student_id='{{ student.student.id }}' name='completed' value='{{ class.id }}'>{{ item.completed }}</td>
</form>
```

```
def post_form_api(request):
    data = {}

    if request.method == "POST":
        class_id = request.POST.get("class_id")
        student_id = request.POST.get("student_id")

        student_class_data_entry = get_object_or_404(StudentClassData, student_id=student_id, class_id=class_id)

        form = StudentClassDataForm(request.POST, instance=student_class_data_entry)
        
        [.. other logic .]

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            data = {'result' : True}

        if request.is_ajax():
            return JsonResponse(data)
        else:
            return HttpResponseBadRequest()
```

```
$(".class_complete").click(function(e){
    var csrfToken = $("input[name='csrfmiddlewaretoken']");
    class_id = $(this).attr('value');
    student_id = $(this).attr('student_id');

    var checked = $('#'+e.target.id).is(":checked");

    $.ajax({ url: "/api/post_form/",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {'completed':checked, 'student_id':student_id, 'class_id':class_id, 'csrfmiddlewaretoken':csrfToken.val()},
        cache: false
    }).done(function(data) {
        if (data.result === true){
        }
        else {
        }
    });
});
```

Thank you.

Comment: Why are you passing `student_id` to the template in the first place? Just implement the view such that it only updates the student associated with `request.user`.

Comment: The right approach is to make it "not sensitive". It's kind of unacceptable from the security point of view that one user can change another user's data so what you need to do is to get this sorted, not hash the student id. You do this by making sure that the student_id matches to the student_id of the current user.

Comment: @Selcuk sorry, i forgot to add, this is a page a Teacher has access to. They can view their Students and select the checkboxes for the units they have completed (which goes through ajax). So I need to know which of the Teacher's Students the checkbox belongs to

Comment: Then simply validate if the teacher has permission to modify the records of the student(s) submitted in the view level. Obfuscating the student id is not a secure solution (they might have seen the hash for a different student on a different teacher's computer).